# Use dates from variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, solr

I am writing a python code in python3 to get values from apache solr. The code works good when the dates in the query are hard coded. I would like to pass the dates by defining it in a variable.

This works good:

```
query='http://x.x.x.x:8983/solr/test/select?fq=timestamp:%5b2020-10-01T00:00:00.000Z%20TO%202020-10-31T23:59:59.999Z%5d&q=*:*'
```

Expected:

```
query='http://x.x.x.x:8983/solr/test/select?fq=timestamp:%5b'first_dayT00:00:00.000Z%20TO%20'last_day'T23:59:59.999Z%5d&q=*:*'

first_day = "2020-10-01"

last_day = "2020-10-31"
```

What is the issue with the expected query?

Answer (score 1):

You could use any of the following:

```
first_day = "2020-10-01"
last_day = "2020-10-31"
```

- Using String Concatenation

> `query = "http://x.x.x.x:8983/solr/test/select?fq=timestamp:%5b" + first_day + "T00:00:00.000Z%20TO%20" + last_day + "T23:59:59.999Z%5d&q=:"`

- `f string` - *Works only in Python 3.6 and above*

> `query = f"http://x.x.x.x:8983/solr/test/select?fq=timestamp:%5b{first_day}T00:00:00.000Z%20TO%20{last_day}T23:59:59.999Z%5d&q=:"`

Comment: f-strings not required, as one can use `query = "http://x.x.x.x:8983/solr/test/select?fq=timestamp:%5b{first_day}T00:00:00.000Z%20TO%20{last_day}T23:59:59.999Z%5d&q=:".format(**dict(first_day="2020-10-01", last_day="2020-10-31"))` in earlier versions of Python 3 (as well as version 2.7).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `f-string` to insert the variables to the string

```
query = f'http://x.x.x.x:8983/solr/test/select?fq=timestamp:%5b{first_day}T00:00:00.000Z%20TO%20{last_day}T23:59:59.999Z%5d&q=:'
```

Or using `format()`

```
query = 'http://x.x.x.x:8983/solr/test/select?fq=timestamp:%5b{}T00:00:00.000Z%20TO%20{}T23:59:59.999Z%5d&q=:'.format(first_day, last_day)
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables are not being inserted inside the string properly. For doing that, you should look up [format_strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) in python3.

for fixing the `query`, you can do this

```
query=f'http://x.x.x.x:8983/solr/test/select?fq=timestamp:%5b{first_day}T00:00:00.000Z%20TO%20{last_day}T23:59:59.999Z%5d&q=:'
```